# Update and test assets on iPhone without rebuilding the application

Tags: ios, resources

We are developing an iPhone game and I would like to know if is possible to copy new or updated assets (images, animations, sounds or whatever) on the device and test them without rebuilding the application in XCode.

We would like to simplify the production pipeline process and we are trying to avoid our artists to rebuild the application every time they modify the assets.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Fede

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I did it in one of my projects.

My strategy was easy, at the start, I stored the new assets in the app documents folder using a wifi tool specially created for that. Then, when the game needed a resource it checked if it was at the documents folder, if there was, it loaded, if not, it loaded the one from the bundle.

Comment: Ok, that's interesting. Maybe we can use this approach in debug and skip it in release. Thank you!

Comment: Yep, that's the idea. My client used it to update the levels w/o rebuild the app in the alpha builds. At beta it was removed. Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

No, because any files that are updated in the XCode side will need to be rebundled and rebuilt. I'm surprised that this is an issue because the build process is remarkably faster between cleans. You're probably not rebuilding the entire application from scratch (ie after a Clean) each time, are you? XCode should detect any resource changes and update them on the device.

Comment: Thank for the reply Justin. 
You are right, we are not rebulding the entire application. At this point I had to specify two facts. 
The first is that we are trying to avoid our artists to open and use Xcode. Maybe a command line script would solve this problem.
The second fact is that we are packaging all the assets inside a single file (we use this approach for the console version of the game and we would like to keep it for the iOS). So, even if just an asset is changed...the whole file must be updated.